# Receive and handle a notification arguments when the Windows (phone) 8.1 app is on foreground

Tags: c#, notifications, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

When I receive a notification and top on the badge or from the notification center the app opens with `OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)` in the `App.xaml.cs` file. I take the arguments from `e.Arguments` and do whatever I want to do with it.

Is there a way to get those arguments when I receive a notification and I am in the app (on foreground)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
PushNotificationChannel currentChannel = myChannel;
currentChannel.PushNotificationReceived += OnPushNotificationReceived;

void OnPushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs e)
{  
    e.Cancel = true; // True to prevent default processing of the notification by Windows
    // implement your logic there
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to prevent the default processing of the notification by Windows?

Comment: you can handle your push message in foreground and choose behavior: if you setup `true` - default toast notification doesn't seem and you can manage like you want

Comment: try look here: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-app-activated-by-a-toast-notification/

Comment: also, look content of xml. you can find need argument, which you retrieve from WNS